# Allow multiple programs to access the same V4L2 device

Tags: video, camera

I'd like to be able to capture input from a webcam to to separate programs. One for VoIP, and one for capture.

The problem is - Linux will allow only one process to access a V4L2 device, so once I run the videochat, the capture will get black frames, if I start the capture program first, the videochat will get black frames.

How can I solve this? Is there a way to allow multiple processes to access a single `/dev/video` device? Or maybe I can clone the `/dev/video0` and create a `/dev/video1` somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [v4l2loopback](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/) to create multiple virtual devices, one per program that wants access to the stream, and then use a program such as `tee` to forward the video to the virtual devices.

Comment: Could you point me to some sources on how do I do this? I have no idea how v4l2loopback works.

Comment: I have tried using g-streamer solution, but and it gave me a cloned `/dev/video1`, but `/dev/video0` didn't work, so gain. I wasn't able to create 2 cloned devices.

Comment: Related [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165727/is-it-possible-for-two-processes-to-access-the-webcam-at-the-same-time/509681#509681)

Comment: I have been using v4l2loopback for a long time. Recently, I've discovered that virtual devices can make multiple streams at the same time. Now, I wanted to know if phisical cameras can do that by configuring them in any way... could it be possible?